# Phonegap application consuming more battery in background

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap

I have done application using phonegap. When I open and minimize or Left the app in background and after a few hours got a warning that the App is consuming power. Could not get the complete message. How to resolve this issue. is there any plugin to avoid background battery consummation. For more reference I have attached screen within.

[image]